# How do Vite MPAs using the Vue plugin work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have a Vite app created and I need it to have multiple pages. I read the docs and found how to do this ([can be found here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app)), however when I run the server I get a blank page.

My `vite.config.js` file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

const { resolve } = require('path')

module.exports = {
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        home: resolve(__dirname, 'src/Home/index.html')
      }
    }
  }
}

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

Here's what my file structure looks like:

[image: Image here]

**Edit:** I have changed the config to what tony posted below, but it is still showing a blank page.

**Edit 2:** I found out that you don't need to use the vite.config.js routing, there's an easier way
Create a copy of your main.js, App.vue, and index.html file and rename them to something different. After you rename them change the `<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>` to your new JS file, and change the `.vue` file import in your new main.js to your new `.vue` file. Here's my new structure:
[image]

All I did was copy the files and change the names and imports, and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two default exports in `vite.config.js`, but there should only be one:

```js
module.exports = { 1️⃣
  //...
}

export default defineConfig({ 2️⃣
  //...
})
```

The config should be:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        home: resolve(__dirname, 'src/Home/index.html')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-contrib/vite-mpa-demo)